# Dual axis starting point comes different in column chart

Tags: highcharts

We have two series of data in high chart, those have big difference in value then staring point for these comes different like : [image]

Can we start it from the same point for these?

Comment: Could you then please explain what display do you exactly expect? And it's best if you recreate this example in an online editor such as JSFiddle so that we can test it? Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t06hvxs8/

Comment: Hi Team I have created an example as :
https://jsfiddle.net/thakurlal_pandey/3ftnkcav/1/

Here we can show the start point for both axis values 0 is not aligned, is there any way to make it ?

Comment: Check out this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hvx0fbtu/